# Add separate xml layout to this xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I'm trying a little experiment with the cards ui library and a contact list.  I want (for example) all As to appear on 1 card.  so I'm trying to add a relative layout containing a textview and imageview for each new name added.  I thought I figured it out but I'm getting a nullpoint on my "addview". I'm under the assumption that I'm simply going about this the wrong way.  What would be a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

The parent xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_contact_info_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_contact_letter"
            style="@style/CardTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="title" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/stroke" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The xml I want to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_contact_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_cardbank"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_contact_name"
        style="@style/CardText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="Contact Name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_contact_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How I'm trying to add it:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contacts_fragment,
                container, false);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainactivity_contact_name, container);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_contact_info_holder);


        for (int i = 0; i < contactArray.size(); i++) {

            TextView contactName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_name);

            contactName.setText(contactArray.get(i).mName);

            ll.addView(rowView);
        }

        mCardView = (CardUI) view.findViewById(R.id.cardsview);
        mCardView.setSwipeable(false);

        MyCard newCard = new MyCard("First Letter");
        mCardView.addCard(newCard);

        mCardView.refresh();

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Uhm... you might want to check out what a ListView is.

Comment: I'm purposely not using a listview.  LIke I said, I'm testing the capability of the cards ui library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.  I forgot to inflate the layout holding the linearlayout.  2 days and I was missing it this whole time